# Can nginx be configured to timeout when downloading a large file from the proxied server as part of a request?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

My nginx pulls a large file from the proxied server and I want it to fail if it takes longer than a certain time to download this file. I saw the:

`proxy_read_timeout` flag, which

> Defines a timeout for reading a response from the proxied server. The timeout is set only between two successive read operations, not for the transmission of the whole response. If the proxied server does not transmit anything within this time, the connection is closed.

This sounds like it won't interrupt an ongoing read operation. I can confirm this because this defaults to 60s and I know it's not interrupting my download, because I haven't set it and my download takes comfortably longer than 60s.

Is there another flag or way to do this?